# Linker error using gcc and clang together on macos sierra

Tags: macos, gcc, clang

I have to compile c++ code with *g++ 6.4.0* (Homebrew g++-6) to a static lib, which is then wrapped into a C static lib (Homebrew gcc-6) and linked to a *clang++* (clang 8.1.0) app on *macos sierra*. So the picture is:

```
c++ (gcc) wrapped in c (gcc) linked to clang app.
```

As a testcase I use *shared-lib.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void foo()
{
  cerr << "Hi from the shared lib" << endl;
}
```

together with *shared-lib.h*

```
extern void foo();
```

and *wrapper-lib.c*

```
#include "shared-lib.h"
int wrapper()  
{
  foo();
  return 123;
}
```

along with *wrapper-lib.h*

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

extern int wrapper();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The *main.cpp* that uses all the libs looks like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "shared-lib.h"
#include "wrapper-lib.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto s = "Hello world from main";
    cout << s << endl;
    foo(); // from c++ lib

    int result = wrapper();  // from c wrapper lib
    cout << "wrapper returned " << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My test built script is

```
g++-6 --version
echo -----------------------

echo build shared-lib .o with g++
g++-6 -c -Wall -fpic -std=c++11 shared-lib.cpp

echo build a wrapper library in C with gcc
gcc-6 -c -Wall -fpic  wrapper-lib.c

echo build static libshared-lib.a
ar rcs libshared-lib.a  shared-lib.o

echo build static libwrapper-lib.a
ar rcs libwrapper-lib.a  wrapper-lib.o

echo build main with clang
clang++ --version
echo ----------------------
clang++ -v -L/Users/worker -Wall -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -lwrapper-lib  -lshared-lib main.cpp -o main

echo start the app
./main
```

If I only call the gcc c++ function *foo()* then everything works fine.
If I call the C wrapper function *wrapper()*, then clang comes up with:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_foo", referenced from:
      _wrapper in libwrapper-lib.a(wrapper-lib.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Maybe someone can simply spot, what's wrong with my workflow?

**Note**, for completeness the whole build script output

**Note2**, since *ar* in the gcc@6 toolchain does not work (liblto_plugin.so missing) I use clang's *ar* tool...

```
mac-mini:~ worker$ ./build-test.sh
g++-6 (Homebrew GCC 6.4.0) 6.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

-----------------------
build shared-lib .o with g++
build a wrapper library in C with gcc
build static libshared-lib.a
build static libwrapper-lib.a
build main with clang
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.41)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
----------------------
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.41)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ [-Wdeprecated]
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.12.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu penryn -target-linker-version 278.4 -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.1.0 -stdlib=libstdc++ -Wall -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/worker -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 166 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.12.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/18/m18t0kxx03d7__31kg3wrsr40000gq/T/main-337db7.o -x c++ main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.41) default target x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/i686-apple-darwin10/x86_64"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.0.0"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.0.0/i686-apple-darwin8/"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.0.0/backward"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1
 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.1.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.12.0 -o main -L/Users/worker -lwrapper-lib -lshared-lib /var/folders/18/m18t0kxx03d7__31kg3wrsr40000gq/T/main-337db7.o -lstdc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.1.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_foo", referenced from:
      _wrapper in libwrapper-lib.a(wrapper-lib.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Oops. it looks like, this is **not a GCC - Clang issue**, as the linker error occurs also if I try everything purely with clang++ / clang. So the question now is **how to get rid of the nasty linker error that remains, if I try to wrap a  static c++ lib in a plain c library..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compile `shared-lib.cpp` with:

```
g++-6 -c -Wall -fpic -std=c++11 shared-lib.cpp
```

And you compile `wrapper-lib.c` with:

```
gcc-6 -c -Wall -fpic  wrapper-lib.c
```

Have a look at the symbol table of `shared-lib.o`. It's something like:

```
$ readelf -s shared-lib.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 24 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS shared-lib.cpp
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     4: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
     5: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5 
     6: 0000000000000000     1 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    5 _ZStL19piecewise_construc
     7: 0000000000000000     1 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 _ZStL8__ioinit
     8: 0000000000000032    73 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 _Z41__static_initializati
     9: 000000000000007b    21 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 _GLOBAL__sub_I_shared_lib
    10: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6 
    11: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    9 
    12: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   10 
    13: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    8 
    14: 0000000000000000    50 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _Z3foov
    15: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
    16: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZSt4cerr
    17: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcE
    18: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_trait
    19: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
    20: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
    21: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL HIDDEN   UND __dso_handle
    22: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
    23: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __cxa_atexit
```

(I'm working on Ubuntu, not OS X.)

Note that there is only one global function defined in this object file and
its name is `_Z3foov`.

That's the [mangled name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C.2B.2B) of the C++ function called `foo` in `shared-lib.cpp`. That's
the name the linker sees.

Now the symbol table of `wrapper-lib.o`:

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 11 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS wrapper-lib.c
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     4: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
     5: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6 
     6: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7 
     7: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5 
     8: 0000000000000000    21 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 wrapper
     9: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
    10: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND foo
```

This object file makes an undefined reference to `foo`, because `wrapper-lib.c`
is a C source file and you compiled it as such. C does not mangle names. No definition
of `foo` is provided by any object file in your linkage, so it fails with that
symbol unresolved.

To avoid this and accomplish your linkage, you can direct the C++ compiler
*not to mangle the name* `foo`, when compiling `shared-lib.cpp`. You do so like:

**shared-lib.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {

void foo()
{
  cerr << "Hi from the shared lib" << endl;
}

} //extern "C"
```

Enclosing the definition of `foo` in `extern "C" {...}` has no effect on
C++ compilation *except* the one you want: the symbol `foo` will be emitted
as a C symbol; not mangled.

Having done that, you must of course follow suit in `shared-lib.h`:

**shared-lib.h**

```
#ifndef SHARED_LIB_H
#define SHARED_LIB_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void foo();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

With those corrections, let's try again:

```
$ g++-6 -c -Wall -fpic -std=c++11 shared-lib.cpp
```

and check the symbol table:

```
$ readelf -s shared-lib.o | grep foo
    14: 0000000000000000    50 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 foo
```

Now the one global function defined is `foo`, not `_Z3foov`, and your
linkage will succeed.

If you want to write a C++ library that *exports a C++ API and not a C API* to
the linker, then you cannot call its API from C except by discovering the
mangled names of the API (with `readelf`, `nm`, `objdump`) and explicitly
calling those *mangled* names from C. Thus without those `extern "C"` fixes,
your linkage would also succeed with:

**wrapper-lib.c**

```
extern void _Z3foov(void); 
int wrapper()  
{
  _Z3foov();
  return 123;
}
```

Comment: Ahh that was it! Thanks a lot for your solution. The only thing now is, that in my case the **c++ library** I need to wrap into a **C lib** is a **static version of Qtcore**. So does that mean, I have to put **extern "C"** around zillions of Qt source code lines? Sounds like fun ;-)

Comment: @xy @xy I'm afraid that's a non-starter. `extern "C"` {...}` will give you C API provided `...` *is syntactically a C API*, but C++ *class definitions* obviously aren't. Except for `POD` structs, you cannot expose *classes* as C.